# List Highlighted files to a file list. (Windows Batch)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, filelist

Is it possible (In windows batch) to list a bunch of highlighted files to a file list. Is there an Environment Variable for it?

Comment: By highlighted, you mean selected ?

Comment: Yea I do, is it possible?

Comment: Where? If in a folder window, Shift + right click and choose Copy As Path.

Comment: Well then in that case, can Windows Batch files store text copied to the clipboard to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to play with %* variable of batch.

Drag-and-drop one or more files on a batch and it should get it:

```
echo %*
```

Note: You can also use %1, %2, %3 ... but this is limited to %9.

Comment: Exactly how would one set that up? would you use the user input of set /p ?

Comment: Just drag-and-drop files onto a .bat

Comment: to get them line by line, use `for %%i in (%*) do echo %%i`